# How i get parent parent toolbar name

Tags: java, android, kotlin

In my android app, in AdapterActivity i get toolbar name from MainActivity with intent

in AdapterActivity I have list, with click will open DetailActivity.class
For DetailActivity i send data in Adapter method is onCreateViewHolder

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_item_sozder, parent, false)
    val holder = ViewHolder(view)
    view.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(parent.context, DetailActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("TILEK", alphabets[holder.adapterPosition].kaz)
        parent.context.startActivity(intent)
    }
    return holder

}
```

How can i sent toolbar name for DetailActivity from MainActivity's intent

Answer (score 1):

You can get/set toolbar Tile like this way

```
var title=(context as YourActivity).supportActionBar?.title             //getter
(context as YourActivity).supportActionBar?.title ="my new title"      //setter
```

Comment: how i get parent parent toolbar name?